# SQL query select return empty resultset in distant server but not when running locally

Tags: java, sql, unix, jdbc, db2

I have a select query that is suppose to return the number of request in a table, that fits certain criterias. When I run it locally, in my eclipse IDE, it returns the number request, but when I deploy it in a distant server, it returns 0. I'm using java, with a db2 client, with jdbc and the server is a unix server. There's no error, on ther server, it returns nothing, but locally  it returns the number of records. It's the same database, table, same username and password, just different results on the server and local. `What could be the reason for that?

Here is the query:

```sql
select count(numconfirmation) as recordCount from edm.tdemande where (typedemande not in ('1', '4', '105', '66', '75', '76', '78', '12', '84', '60', '61', '42', '42S', '43', '43S', '44', '2', '5', '40', '7', '2S', '3S', '6', '3', '30', '31', '13', '15', '22', '23', '24', '25', '36', '82', '33', '34', '35', '37', '38', '39', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '88', '89', '90', '91', '93', '14', '70', '73', '74', '18', '29', '87') or codedomaff in ('MAR','AFF','DFCE')) and datecreation < ?  with ur
```

Comment: The local DB's table contains different data from the remote DB's table? (or, when you say "the same database" do you mean the same JDBC connection URL to the same server and the same physical DB?) Or, there is an error but your code has swallowed it, instead of logging it (maybe unlikely)? Some other reason? There isn't much info for us to go on.

Comment: What's the `edm.tdemande.datecreation` column data type? It's a prepared statement according to the `datecreation < ?` expression. Edit your question with your java code showing the data type of the parameter and the actual parameter value you get unexpected result on.